# Codecademy: Ruby 'Loops & Iterators' Exercise 5.9

Tags: ruby, loops, modulo

The question prompt is:

> The next keyword can be used to skip over certain steps in the loop.
>   For instance, if we ***don't* want to print out the even numbers**, we
>   can write:
>
> ```
> i = 20
> loop do
>   i -= 1
>   next if i % 2 == 0
>   print "#{i}"
>   break if i <= 0
> end
> ```

Wouldn't this actually print out the even numbers? The way I would read the above is, i = 20, it gets decremented to 19, the if statement is false, so nothing gets printed and the loop cycles once again. This time i = 18, the if statement is true, and 18 gets printed.

But lo and behold, when you do the exercise the above code prints out 19, 17, 15, and so on. What's going on here? Does the decrement occur after the if statement is evaluated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if statement is false, so nothing gets printed

Why do you think so? When `i` is `19`, the `if`-statement is `false`, so it does not skip the iteration, and the `print` in the next line is executed. When `i` is `18`, the `if`-statement is `true`, so it is skipped to the `next` iteration without executing the `print` in the next line.

Comment: I see, so 'next' means SKIP the code below if the 'if-statement' is true? I understood it to mean continue if the 'if-statement' is true.

Comment: `next` means to skip the code below. The `if`-modifier means to execute whatever it modifies (in this case `next`) if the statement is true. Maybe you are confusing the block-style `if` condition and the `if`-modifier.

Comment: I just understood it to mean complete the *next* code if the 'if-statement' is true, but now I see it means to move to the next cycle of the loop. Thanks.